# How to go from System.currentTimeMillis() to hhmmssSSS in Java?

Tags: java, date, time, calendar, epoch

I have a long with the EPOCH time. I want to do some math and go to a hhmmssSSS number. Any math/date wizards out there who could help me? Thanks!

Comment: Not duplicated !!!!!!!! Using math, not a formatter!

Comment: See the duplicate of that duplicate.

Comment: You use math the same way you would turn a number into a String. Using a combination of `%` and `/` The difference is that sometime you use `10` and sometime you use `6` depending on whether the digit has 10 or 6 possible values.  BTW If you don't want GMT, you will need to adjust for the time zone.

Comment: See here for an example https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Lang/blob/master/lang/src/main/java/net/openhft/lang/io/AbstractBytes.java#L1218